# Export a sprite kit scene as an image at full size

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I have a program that used sktilemap and noise map to generate maps. At the end i have a code to export the scene as an image, but the image is cropped and i see less content in the saved image than at screen (see screen capture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiIWq.jpg) and image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWiV0.jpg))[image: Screen Capture]
[image: Image saved by my program]
The code :

```
let w = nCol*16
let h = nLig*16
let texture = self.view?.texture(from: scene!, crop: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: w, height: h)))
let image = texture?.cgImage()
let path = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/MyName/testExport.png")
writeCGImage(image!, to: path)


@discardableResult func writeCGImage(_ image: CGImage, to destinationURL: URL) -> Bool {
    guard let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(destinationURL as CFURL, kUTTypePNG, 1, nil) else { return false }
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image, nil)
    return CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)
}
```

edit : If i use self.view?.texture(from: scene!) i have the same result
If i increase the size of the crop, i have a pic [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2Oe3.jpg) in high resolution (10240 × 5760 during my test) but i don't see more things, i see a background
[image: Image with higher crop dimensions]

edit2 : with your answers i was able to find the solution : for export i had to change the scene size like that :

```
scene?.size.height = CGFloat(nLig*tileSize)
scene?.size.width = CGFloat(nCol*tileSize)
```

The result is an image too heavy for imgur : you can see it https://twitter.com/GenetixVideos/status/1233686731200909312/photo/2

Comment: What happens if you use `texture(from:)` instead of `texture(from:crop:)`? If that shows much more of the scene, likely the crop is just wrong.

Comment: texture(from:) give me the same result and change crop size give a biggest picture  but i don't see more things, i see a background (third picture)

Comment: It looks like the expanded crop did indeed capture the whole screen (plus the extra black background). I'd try making a sprite from the (original crop) texture and seeing if that shows the whole scene. If it does, then the problem has to be something in the extraction to a CGImage and writing steps.

Comment: One thought is that it may have something to do with resolution issues. A texture has a given number of pixels which the CGImage will reflect, but that's not the same as the screen resolution in points. On an iPad, e.g., it's generally 2x bigger because of the retina screen.

Comment: do you have a root node?  normally a world scene node?  Use that instead of the scene.

Comment: Also, your texture is going to have a limited size of 2048x2048 i believe (it may have changed to 4096x4096) so keep that in mind.  Also, @bg2b is correct.  A CGImage is going to give you pixels, not points, so your PNG is going to be 2x ->3x the size of your scene, depending on device.  I believe the only devices still using 1x are that on tvOS.

Comment: I have found solution because of you, thank you, you can see results here https://twitter.com/GenetixVideos/status/1233686731200909312/photo/2